# El comando 'preview' de vite funciona, pero no puedo visualizar el proyecto desde el archivo index.html

Tags: javascript, build, vite, svelte

Comencé un proyecto en **svelte** con **vite**, hice mi código y todo funciona con `npm run dev` (en modo desarrollo). Pero cuando ejecuto `npm run build` (para compilar el proyecto) y abro **/dist/index.html** no funciona.

Probablemente estoy haciendo algo mal. Sé que cuando ejecuto `npm run build && npm run preview` funciona. Pero estoy tratando de hacer que funcione abriendo solo el archivo index.html, porque es la única forma en que podría alojarlo en mi servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes mostrarnos que error te sale por consola, si de pronto no te está cargando algún archivo que espera. Por ejemplo, que el main lo estés llamando desde el index en el directorio de src. Recuerda que todo lo que se encuentre en src no será contemplado en el despliegue, excepto la carpeta public.